# Summing in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question  hope someone can help me.

I have 3 different range inputs on my page:

```
<input type="range" name="test1" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="5" onchange="showValue(this.value) 
<input type="range" name="test2" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="5" onchange="showValue(this.value)
<input type="range" name="test3" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="5" onchange="showValue(this.value)
```

and I want JS to calculate the sum of the values of the inputs that the user selects, like (test1 + test2 + test3) and then display the result.

Regards.

Comment: create a jsfiddle and show us what you have done so far

Comment: I think what you're asking is how can I access my input elements and add their values . In traditional javascript you can go with document.getElementsByTagName("input") , loop over the array it returns and add to a result variable. If this is unclear you should read more on DOM accessing and event handling before continuing ...hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```
<script>
var update = function() {
    var sum = 
      Array.prototype.slice.call(
        document.getElementsByClassName("rangefield")
      ).reduce(
        function (a, b) {
          return a + Number(b.value);
        },
        0
      );
    document.getElementById("sumresult").innerHTML = sum;
};
</script>

<input type="range" class="rangefield" onchange="update()" onkeyup="update()">
<input type="range" class="rangefield" onchange="update()" onkeyup="update()">
<input type="range" class="rangefield" onchange="update()" onkeyup="update()">
<div id="sumresult"></div>
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ysangkok/nVNjk/1/

### How it works

1. When a field is updated, the `update()` function is called
2. The update function consists of two statements. I'll walk you through their execution in the order that it occurs.
3. `document.getElementsByClassName` is called and returns an `HTMLCollection`. This collection is not an array.
4. Since I want an array, I convert the `HTMLCollection` to one using `Array.prototype.slice.call`.
5. Now that I have an `Array`, I call it's [reduce member](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) which allows me to walk through the elements and pass state from invocation to invocation of the function it takes.
6. The arguments of reduce that I supply are: the function which is called for each value, and the initial value (0).
7. The function will be called three times, first with the first range-input as `a` and 0 as `b`. Then it will return the sum of the value of the range-input and 0, which is the intermediate sum after looking at 1 element. The following calls to the anonymous function will sum the intermediate sums with the two other input fields' values.
8. Now that the `sum` variable is assigned, we put it in the `sumresult` element for display by assigning the `innerHTML` property of the element with the ID of `sumresult` (retrieved using `document.getElementById`).